# What is the best way to secure Apache Camel endpoints?

Tags: security, https, apache-camel, cxf

We have several internal web applications/services in our company which can only be accessed from LAN. Now, we have a public web portal hosted in Internet, and this portal needs to be access some internal services.

To meet this requirement, I plan to use Apache Camel in a ServerMix to route the requests from web portal to local web services.
The exposed endpoints will use **Jetty(HTTP)** or **CXF** protocol. As you can see, we must secure those endpoints, since they will also be exposed on Internet.

I read through the Camel website, camel support Shiro security for authentication and authorization. However, I think Shiro is too heavy in our scenario. Because we only have one web portal to be authenticated. And Shiro will to encrypt payload, that means the username and password will be transported in plain text.

So I consider to use HTTPS, but I am new to HTTPS. How HTTPS authenticate request application? Should I use 2-way HTTPS?

Please clear me out here, an example will be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Read through this section, it would explain how you can have a secure cxf endpoint:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Security_Guide/files/CamelCXF.html

If you didn't manage to create your secure endpoint, let me know and I'll create an example for you.